# Some settings seem useless in DRF Social OAuth2

Tags: django-rest-framework, token, google-signin, python-social-auth

So i am using [DRF Social Oauth2](https://github.com/wagnerdelima/drf-social-oauth2#drf-social-oauth2) to implement social authentication in DRF.

While setting the `settings.py` we need many things to do like adding some apps to installed apps etc.

We also need to set these two settings;

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = 'google_client_id'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'google_client_secret'
```

But as we create a google console app for android, it doesnot provide any secret but only client_Id.

What i did is i just removed `SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'google_client_secret'` from the settings and my api still worked fine. It gave the response without any errors.

After that, i tried to remove `SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = 'google_client_id'` also and still my api worked fine.

So i am now confused why we use them? Why is my app working fine even without client_id and secret?

This is how i send the request;

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/social/auth/token
```

body of the request;

```
{
    "grant_type": "password",
    "username": "myusername",
    "password": "mypassword",
    "client_id": "client id created in my backend when creating a new application for the social login (different from google client id)",
    "client_secret": "client secret created in my backend when creating a new application for the social login (different from google client secret)"
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
  "access_token": "some_token",
  "expires_in": 36000,
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "scope": "read write",
  "refresh_token": "some_other_token"
}
```

Another request to save a user;

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/social/auth/convert_token

{
    "token": "token recieved from frontend from google",
    "backend": "google-oauth2",
    "grant_type": "convert_token",
    "client_id": "...",
    "client_secret": "..."
}
```

OUTPUT is same as the first request and it also adds the details to the database.

Comment: Does it still work even if you ask for a new access token?

Comment: Yes it works. Let me edit my question to show how i send the request.

Comment: Ok did you build the request manually? If you are not using `SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET`, where did the value in the request come from?

Comment: As i mentioned in the question, i am using DRF Social oauth2 which provides these credentials while settings an application for the social authentication.

Comment: First i thought that maybe it is just creating the tokens but i am really surprised to see that it is able to access the google account data and stores that in the database.

Comment: Is it possible that the data can be obtained from the token provided b the google?

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have solved this already. First things first, the endpoints in [drf-social-oauth2](https://github.com/wagnerdelima/drf-social-oauth2) do not have the social/ before the auth/. You can check the endpoints demonstration here: https://github.com/wagnerdelima/drf-social-oauth2#testing-the-setup.

So you should fire to http:127.0.0.1:8000/auth/convert_token.

I don't know why the response is being positive since you removed the valid client and secret ids. However, your newly generated tokens are not necessarily valid since they have not been generated with valid credentials, you see?

P.S: I am the main maintainer of [drf-social-oauth2](https://github.com/wagnerdelima/drf-social-oauth2).

Comment: having social in url is not a big deal. I did it while setting the urls. So ofcourse, that is not a wrong thing. You should check django-urls and how we set them.